# Dapper returns null for SingleOrDefault(DATEDIFF(...))

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, dapper

I have a SQL statement similar to:

`SELECT DATEDIFF(Day, startDate, endDate) FROM Data WHERE ProjectId=@id`

In the case where `Data` doesn't have any records for `ProjectId`, SQL Server returns null.

In Dapper, I execute this via:

`value = conn.Query<int>("...").SingleOrDefault()`

In this case, I expect the semantics of `SingleOrDefault` to mean "if this is null, return zero." In fact, my code is even more zero-friendly:

```
int toReturn = 0;
using (var conn = ...) {
  toReturn = conn.Query<int>("SELECT DATEDIFF(...))");
}
return toReturn;
```

When I debug and step into this code, I find that the line `yield return (T)func(reader)` is throwing a null pointer exception.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this by design?

(FYI, the work-around is to wrap my select in an `ISNULL(..., 0)`)

Comment: You could also use the c# `?? 0` coalesce operator to supply zero in case of null.  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/20/the-new-c-null-coalescing-operator-and-using-it-with-linq.aspx

Comment: Can I check: are you talking about the case where you return zero rows? or the case where a row is returned with a null?

Comment: @MarcGravell a case where the row returned is null. Not zero rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the case where Data doesn't have any records for ProjectId, SQL Server returns null.

In the case where `Data` doesn't have any matching records, SQL server does not really return null - it returns no rows. This scenario works fine:

```
var result = connection.Query<int>( // case with rows
 "select DATEDIFF(day, GETUTCDATE(), @date)", new { date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(20) })
 .SingleOrDefault();
result.IsEqualTo(20);

result = connection.Query<int>( // case without rows
    "select DATEDIFF(day, GETUTCDATE(), @date) where 1 = 0", new { date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(20) })
    .SingleOrDefault();
result.IsEqualTo(0); // zero rows; default of int over zero rows is zero
```

both of which work fine. The fact that you say `ISNULL` "fixes" it means that you are talking about a different scenario - the "I returned rows" scenario. Since that is the case, what your code is saying is "take this 1-or-more integers which contains a null, and map it as a non-nullable int" - that *isn't possible*, and the mapper is correct to throw an exception. Instead, what you want is:

```
int? result = connection.Query<int?>(...).SingleOrDefault();
```

Now, if there are rows, it is mapping the value to `int?`, and **then** applying the single-or-default. It you want that as an int, then maybe:

```
int result = connection.Query<int?>(...).SingleOrDefault() ?? 0;
```

If you need to be able to tell the difference between "zero rows" and "null result", then I would suggest:

```
class NameMe {
    public int? Value {get;set;}
}
var row = connection.Query<NameMe>("select ... as [Value] ...", ...)
                    .SingleOrDefault();
if(row == null) {
   // no rows
} else if(row.Value == null) {
   // one row, null value
} else {
   // one row, non-null value
}
```

or something similar

Comment: @ashes999 absolutely! your sql code is **returning a null**. You can't map a null into an `int`, hence the error. `SingleOrDefault` is meaningless if the actual step of getting the first row is invalid. I would suggest: "return no rows" - if you do that, it'll work great. But returning a `null` and asking it to push it into a non-nullable `int`... how is that ever going to work? But if you change it to `Query<int?>(...)` then it *will* work. It is entirely possible to represent a `null` in an `int?`

Comment: Okay, my bad. I expected "SingleOrDefault" to mean "under any wierd conditions (no rows, null, etc.) return the default (0)." Thanks for vetting the design though and explaining it :)